# Linux - multiple command execution using semicolon

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a scenario where I need to execute date command and `ls -lrth|wc -l` command at the same time.

I read somewhere on google that I can do it in the way shown below using the semicolon

```
ls -lrth | wc -l | ; date
```

This works super fine!
But the problem is when I want to extract the output of this. This gives a two line output with the output of `ls -lrth |wc -l` in the first line and the second line has the date output like shown below

```
$ cat test.txt 
39
Mon Oct 26 16:11:20 IST 2015
```

But it seems like linux is treating these two lines as if its on the same line.
I want this to be formatted to something like this

```
39,Mon Oct 26 16:11:20 IST 2015
```

For doing this I am not able to separately access these two lines (not even with tail or head).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Why I think linux is treating this as a same line because when I do this as shown below,

```
 $ ls -lrth| wc -l;date | head -1
39
Mon Oct 26 16:24:07 IST 2015
```

The above reason is for my assumption of the one line thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you already tried using an echo?

```
echo $(ls | wc -l) , $(date)
```

(or something similar, I don't have a Linux emulator here)

Answer (score 1):

If you want in your script
./script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(ls -lrth | wc -l)
b=$(date)
out="$a,$b"
echo "$out"
```

**EDIT**

ls -lrth| wc -l;date | head -1

The semicolon simply separates two different commands ";"

Answer (score 0):

Pipe to `xargs echo -n` (-n means no newline at end):

```
ls -lrth | wc -l | xargs echo -n ; echo -n ","; date
```

Testing:

```
$ ls -lrth | wc -l | xargs echo -n ; echo -n ","; date
11,Mon Oct 26 12:57:14 EET 2015
```

Comment: Alternatively, pipe to `xargs printf "%i, "`